# How to debug a website template which is very slow (client side)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, profiling

A client has purchased a website template and wants me to work with it. However, for whatever reason, the template is very slow and makes the browser hang / slow down, particularly when scrolling down.

The issue is in the client side code (javascript, flash, images, or CSS), and not on the server side.

How can I debug this site to try to determine exactly what is causing the template to be slow?

I've tried adding / removing content but it doesn't seem to help, so I think that it might be linked to the css

Comment: Seems you can provide a few more details (specific versions of browsers you've tried, what are the content on this website, etc.)  Seems unusual for slowness to be associated with CSS (are there lots of content?)

Comment: @user1766760 Tried google chrome & ff, yes the template is quite content heavy, i need to locate spefically which of the content is causing the most load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a modern browser, press F-12, clear the cache, open the NETWORK panel and reload the page. This will give you a list of resources, how big the files are and how long they take to transfer and load.

The usual suspect: **images over 100K that comprise UI elements**. I had a friend make a banner that was 2500px wide, but resized it in the CSS to be 960-wide. It still used the same 350K PNG file.

Comment: Found the issue! There was a 1 MB image being linked from CSS, removing it now makes thing smooth. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Besides the network panel in browser's dev tools or Firebug etc. also try YSlow and similar plugins to analyze your page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably has to do with the javascript scroll event.

For example, in jQuery, anything within $(window).scroll(); gets executed every pixel the window moves.

Example: http://codepen.io/coulbourne/pen/omKql

Try debouncing if there is a scroll function

Answer (score 1):

Check the background. Is it an image? That can be one of the causes of your problem.

Other detail which is often forgotten is that resizing images takes time (not too much, but it's something). Try resizing them yourself before putting them to the HTML code.

These two tips can do more than you would expect!
(Please let me know how if it helped!)